# Global Rollout - Record Types Design

Tags: record-type, servicecloud

We are going building a template for global roll-outs in the near future. It's a service cloud implementation with 3-4 different support processes.

Currently we only have 6 different record types tied to 3 support processes. Moving forward, we are getting additional requirements for custom fields that should be visible on the page layouts. So for e.g. - Country A demands for 4 custom fields and country A's page layout is same as Country X,Y and Z.

The record type is the same, so all the countries (A,X,Y,Z) will get the 4 custom fields requested.

So we are currently on the verge of thinking on country specific record types with same labels and different API name. I am aware of the fact that Salesforce recommends no more than 200 record types per object.

Any advice on the design, scalability, support and maintenance going forward?

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Does each country use the same profile?

Comment: Alex - Yes, it does.